# Python SVD script , format Matrix for machine learning

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, svd

I am using the Movielens dataset. The ratings.dat/csv format is

- userId,MovieId,rating,timestamp
- 1,1,5.0,52234234

Initial data set:

```
 user    movie   rating
    1       43      3
    1       57      2
    2       219     4
```

Need to pivot to be:

```
user        1   2
movie   43  3   0
        57  2   0
        219 0   4
```

To make recommendations the matrix needs to be in row(users) columns(movieId) in order to check for similarity. As shown in this tutorial : http://maheshakya.github.io/gsoc/2014/05/18/preparing-a-bench-marking-data-set-using-singula-value-decomposition-on-movielens-data.html

The output I get is something like this :

```
8003 636e 756d 7079 2e63 6f72 652e 6d75
6c74 6961 7272 6179 0a5f 7265 636f 6e73 
7472 7563 740a 7100 636e 756d 7079 0a6e 
6461 7272 6179 0a71 014b 0085 7102 4301
6271 0387 7104 5271 0528 4b01 4dce 024d  
...
...
```

As I understand in order to check for similarity and then make recommendations I need a Matrix where the first row (userId="1") 
has 0-5 (rating) values for each movie.

the python script(I used both .dat and .csv files) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
import pickle
data_file = pd.read_table(r'rat.csv', sep = ',', header=None,engine='python')
users = np.unique(data_file[0])
movies = np.unique(data_file[1])

number_of_rows = len(users)
number_of_columns = len(movies)

movie_indices, user_indices = {}, {}

for i in range(len(movies)):
    movie_indices[movies[i]] = i

for i in range(len(users)):
    user_indices[users[i]] = i
    #scipy sparse matrix to store the 1M matrix
V = sp.lil_matrix((number_of_rows, number_of_columns))

#adds data into the sparse matrix
for line in data_file.values:
    u, i , r , gona = map(int,line)
    V[user_indices[u], movie_indices[i]] = r
    #as these operations consume a lot of time, it's better to save processed data 
with open('movielens_1M.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(V, handle)
    #as these operations consume a lot of time, it's better to save processed data 
#gets SVD components from 10M matrix
u,s, vt = svds(V, k = 10)

with open('movielens_1M_svd_u.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(u, handle)
with open('movielens_1M_svd_s.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(s, handle)
with open('movielens_1M_svd_vt.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(vt, handle)
    s_diag_matrix = np.zeros((s.shape[0], s.shape[0]))

for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    s_diag_matrix[i,i] = s[i]
    X_lr = np.dot(np.dot(u, s_diag_matrix), vt)

with open('movielens.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(X_lr, handle)
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? :)

Comment: the output is not what I am describing , and what the tutorial is showing in the pictures. ratings have 0-5 values

Comment: updated the question